# Datastudio non calculated fields create

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, looker-studio, re2

I connect datastudio with BigQuery.
I try to use user functions in BigQuery and past personal Query in datastudio, but user functions (`CREATE TEMP FUNCTION`) is not supported in datastudio.
Then I try use new non calculated field with categories, but something wrong:

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(campaign, '*-Moskva-*','*-moskva-*') THEN 'Москва' ELSE 'other' END
```

> Error: Invalid formula

Comment: When specifying a query as the data source in Data Studio, did you uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" box?

Comment: Yes, and calculated functions are working (sum (revenue), cost/revenue)

Comment: Does the query work if you use `REGEXP_CONTAINS` instead of `REGEXP_MATCH`? `REGEXP_MATCH` is not a valid function when using standard SQL.

Comment: DataStudio use only this functions:
REGEXP_EXTRACT,
REGEXP_MATCH,
REGEXP_REPLACE,
HYPERLINK

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved using either of the following [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statements:

1) WHEN `campaign` Contains `-Moskva-` or `-moskva-` THEN `Москва`

```sql
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(campaign, ".*(-[Mm]oskva-).*") THEN "Москва"
  ELSE "other"
END
```

2) WHEN `campaign` Contains `Moskva` or `moskva` THEN `Москва`

```sql
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(campaign, ".*([Mm]oskva).*") THEN "Москва"
  ELSE "other"
END
```

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/85ceb1c9-191f-4949-b5dc-fa1aced40f39) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]